# OctoberCMS Backend List format number field as a currency

Tags: octobercms

Wondering if there is an easy way to format Backend List Column values.  Example a number value as a Currency

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to add an accesor on your model according to October's (Laravel) Documentation

https://octobercms.com/docs/database/mutators

```php
<?php
class YourModel
{
    public function getCurrencyColumn($value)
    {
        return money_format('%i', $value)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking too

Answer (score 2):

Its late, but for reference:

If it's only for the backend list, you can easyîly create a new column-type Currency and use that. [see documentation](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#custom-column-types)

In your case you would add the following to your Plugin.php:

```
public function registerListColumnTypes()
{
  return [
    'currency' => function($value) { 
                       return money_format( $value, 2);
                       }
    ];
}
```

Now you can use that in every coulmns.yaml in your plugin:

```
columns
  title:
    label: Title
    type: text
  amount:
    type: currency
    label: Amount
```